# Filter by string and then find variance of the other column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I read my csv file using pandas and then just read these two columns

- Describe_File
- numbers

```
Describe_File   numbers
0   This is the start   25
1   Ending is coming    42
2   Middle of the story 525
3   This is the start   65
4   This is the start   25
5   Middle of the story 35
6   This is the start   28
7   This is the start   24
8   Ending is coming    24
9   Ending is coming    35
10  Ending is coming    25
11  Ending is coming    24
12  This is the start   215
```

So I filter now by a the string name ** This is the start** which looks like this

`df = df[df.Describe_File == "This is the start"]`

```
    Describe_File   numbers
0   This is the start   25
3   This is the start   65
4   This is the start   25
6   This is the start   28
7   This is the start   24
12  This is the start   21
```

And now I just find the variance
`np.var(df)`

**Goal**

Go to **Describe_File**  filter by the all the unique strings and then find the variance and standard deviation of that string.

The output file should look like this

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @wwii , thank you. I have updated the question and the only photo is of the output I am trying to get

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the standard deviation is the square root of the variance. So the following would be the fastest way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_out = df.groupby('Describe_File').apply(np.var)
df_out.columns = ['variance']
df_out['standard_deviation'] = np.sqrt(df_out['variance'])
```

Comment: i  am getting the following error ```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str   ```   . By the way on my code I am filtering by one string and then getting the variance of that string in the ```numbers ``` column

Comment: That seems like an odd error. Are you trying to print out some intermediate results?

Comment: Can you please have a look at the photo, the generated csv file is different from what I am getting in jupyter   [Here is the picture](https://ibb.co/Vjz3jXV)

Comment: That looks like an excel thing (see here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-error-bf801d0a-2a6e-44bd-a70e-0f780ae8f11e). If you widen your columns, or change the decimal position, the numbers should appear. I reckon if you open the csv with a text editor, you would see the results correctly.

Comment: only if I am saving it in a wrong way ```df_out.to_csv('out.csv', sep=';')    ```

Comment: I tried to add the mean like this but I am getting ```Nan  ```.    I am doing this ```df_out['mean']=np.mean(df_out)```